# How to change the rotation of an already existing animation?

Tags: animation, bones, fcurves

I need to change the rotation of an already existing animation, it currently only goes forward but I also want it to go up and down.

I know I can use `R` to rotate but that is only for 1 frame and I need it to be done for a bunch of frames.

I looked up a tutorial on how to do it, but he only needed 1 frame, so that doesn't work for me.

Is there a way to change the rotation of a bunch of frames in bulk? Or do I have to change them all manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graph Editor is what You need to use in this situation. You can edit frames values one by one, all together or even add a modifier, that will create a move, that you want.

Comment: +1, and for example: To turn the animation by 180° around Z, [a generator modifier adding  π rad can be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHGUO.png) (be aware the unit to use in the polynom --rad-- is not the one used for the graph -- degree).